# Create new Dataframe with rows from another Dataframe given the rows index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to create a new dataframe only with the rows which satisfy a certain condition. I got these rows indexes using:

```
position = df.index[df.iloc[:, 0] == value].tolist()
```

How should I create the new dataframe using only the rows which indexes are in the position variable?

Comment: `df1 = df.loc[position]` ?

Comment: `df1 = df[df.iloc[:, 0] == value]`

Comment: That was just it! I did not really think about that, thank you so much!